# Get hidden text of table rows using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My dropdown box is of type "Input" and its values are listed using table.I'm able to get the rows using following code.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("testTable"));
List<WebElement>tr_collection=table.findElements(By.xpath("id('testTable')/tbody/tr"));
```

Row text is retrieved only when the dropdown is clicked and text is displayed.Is it possible to get the text when it is hidden ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `WebElement.GetText()` returns the text visible to a user. To get the hidden text, you can read the `HTMLElement.textContent` property. Though, I would recommend it in a testing context since it doesn't reflect a real usage.

To get the text with `.GetAttribute`:

```c#
string text = element.GetAttribute("textContent");
```

To get the text with `.ExecuteScript`:

```c#
string text = (string)driver.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", element);
```